# Can I automate the finding of -l parameter I use when linking based on header files (gcc)?

Tags: linux, gcc, build-automation, linker

Normally when linking against a static library, I have to specify a library directory and the name of a `libX.so` (or its symbolic link) as `-lX` flag for linking [and its directory with `-L` flag].

Can I automate this based on my header files (in c/c++) only? Or maybe it is not a good idea? Is there a software for locating the `-L` and `-l` parameters automatically? Is some table stored somewhere on the system about this on popular linux systems or even cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pkg-config.

Comment: That's right. Apparently I could just use:
`gcc -o test test.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libpng)`
(from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config )

Comment: Ok, `qi-make` may be useful one day as wel [but is a different thing]:
http://code.google.com/p/qi-make/